# Is it possible to get bluetooth mac address in android jar library?

Tags: java, android, jar, bluetooth

I'm making jar library for android project.  I want to get the android device's bluetooth mac address.  But after M os, mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress(); is not work.
I have to use 
ContentResolver mContentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();
address = Settings.Secure.getString(mContentResolver, SECURE_SETTINGS_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS);

However, in jar library, getting context using getContentResolver() is impossible. Context in jar library is not exist.

How can I get bluetooth mac address or context for bt mac in jar library?  It is not approved to pass context from app to library as input parameter.  Are there any solution in universal way for this situation?

Comment: the only way is to force users' of your library to give you their `Context`, and then you can use it.

Comment: Is it same impossible about remote mac address that is connected to the android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this, may be it will help: 
Do not forget to add permissions:

```
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
```

and then:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // if device does not support Bluetooth
    if(mBluetoothAdapter==null){
        Log.d(TAG,"device does not support bluetooth");
        return null;
    }

    return mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
```

OR you can try to do this in such way:

```
 String bluetoothAddress = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), "bluetooth_address");
```